# Getting ggplot (python) error NameError: name 'stat_function' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, python-ggplot

I'm trying to make a plot using ggplot and I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. Here's the code:

```
from ggplot import *

ggplot(counts, aes(x='pred_prob',y='true_prob',size='count')) + \
    geom_point(color='blue') + \
    stat_function(fun=lambda x: x, color='red') + \
    xlim(-0.05,  1.05) + ylim(-0.05,1.05)
```

Here's the error I get:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-fdefd49237a1> in <module>()
  2 
  3 baseline = np.mean(is_churn)
----> 4 ggplot(counts, aes(x='pred_prob',y='true_prob',size='count')) + geom_point(color='blue') + stat_function(fun=lambda x: x, color='red') + xlim(-0.05,  1.05) + ylim(-0.05,1.05)
NameError: name 'stat_function' is not defined
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. Any ideas? I'm using python 3.5.2 and ggplot version 0.11.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same exact error from the same exact example [code](http://blog.yhat.com/posts/the-beer-bandit.html)

seems the ggplot library had gone through a refactoring.

To install that version use:

```
pip install -U git+https://github.com/yhat/ggpy.git@v0.6.6
```

and then

```
from ggplot import *
from ggplot.stats.stat_function import stat_function # added line
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline

ggplot(pd.DataFrame({'x':[0,500]}), aes(x='x')) + \
    stats.stat_function(fun = lambda x: 50. / (x + 50.)) + \
    ggtitle("Epsilon decay over time") + \
    xlab("amount of feedback") + ylab("epsilon (probability of testing)")
```

It will produce the same figure as in the post

[image]

Comment: I got an error when I tried downloading `pip install -U git+https://github.com/yhat/ggpy.git@v0.6.6` from jupyter. Any idea what I may be doing wrong? `The error is:   File "<ipython-input-45-9ef0b572dfaf>", line 1
    pip install -U git+https://github.com/yhat/ggpy.git@v0.6.6
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Execute that command on your command line, not in the notebook